# Varnish for blocking a Denial of Service attack

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, denial-of-service

What are the changes that should be made to a Varnish default .vcl so that it can effectively block denial of service attacks that it can block?

Comment: "Any form"? Like unplugging the LAN cable, physically destroying the server, having a botnet of 1TB/s upstream request your site at the same time? Seems highly unlikely.

Comment: I am sorry, got a bit excited. Edited to better words.

Comment: I suppose [tag:ddos] is one of the things it can't prevend (the first `d` makes me lose hope) ;)

Comment: @AlexR The only SO tag available to use was ddos, and there was no 'dos' tag for simple denial of service :)

Comment: There is. It's called [tag:denial-of-service] (the long name).

Comment: Oh, my bad again. Missed it.

Answer (score -1):

Bro download a VPN - If you're too cheap to buy a good one with a node from your own country then trying pirating 'HotSpot Shield Elite', it's not great but something.